Embed the whole sharePoint site in MS Teams Tab
Is it possible to still embed SharePoint site in Microsoft Teams?
I was able to do this before by using this team apps - SharePoint and Website
I tried both and they are not working anymore. It seems it only shows pages,lists and libraries.When i use website and click on it it opens into a new page and not embed.
Any solution for this or any recommendation would be appreciated

This approach is still working for us:

Teams App >> App Features >> Personal Tab >>  app=portals adds navigation
You can use dev.teams.microsoft.com to "develop" the app, but in reality - if you just want the link - it's only a few simple clicks.
Edit:

Log in to your tenant as Teams Admin and navigate to dev.teams.microsoft.com
Click on the button: create a new app
Fill out the basic properties - name, id
In app features (you see it in the screenshot on the left hand side), add a personal app >> tab
In the content url, add the url of your SharePoint site



Scroll to the bottom of the menu on the left-hand side and package your app. Download the app package and upload it in your Teams Admin Center. You can also deploy it directly from dev.teams.microsoft.com, but in most tenants this setting is disabled.

Now, as a bonus, there are a few things you can enhance your url with:

SSO :)

https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/sites/FIN/SitePages/Home.aspx
Teamslogon opens the site directly in Teams with Single-SignON.

Navi

?app=portals will give you a SharePoint like navigation (hub site + site navi)

Remove Header


You can also develop a proper app in VS Code, but that's the quickest way to get just a SharePoint link as a teams app.

Thanks grisha for the response. Your recommendation isn't clear. Did you develop an app for this soluton? If yes can you please share the link to the app if you are keen or are you suggesting we develop one for this function

@naijacoder I developed an app, but develop is a big word for the few steps required. I described the steps better in my answer. They don't really require dev skills. Let me know if that helps

Will try it out and let you know thank you
